# Binary Coded Decimal (BCD) in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcd

JavaScript doesn't support data type of `Integer`, or `BCD`.  The only numeric data type is float data type.  Even it's variant `TypeScript` support `number` type is also float data type.

The weakness of using float data type is obvious, it may introduce inaccuracy during calculation.

Is there solutions to overcome the shortage of floating number data type in JavaScript?

Comment: There's a library `decimal.js` that deals with decimals

Comment: Check for example the 'bigint'-library.